# Using Selenium with Firefox in Kiosk mode

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I would like to install a totem in my city with an automation using selenium, which return to the main page after a while.
I've seen that Firefox, according to the official guide, support the "Kiosk Mode".  Is there a way to open a new Firefox windows in this mode, controlled by selenium?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the argument **`--kiosk`** through an instant of `Options()` as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
```